# Understanding proof of The Ratio Root test

Tags: calculus

[image]

[image]

Now this is how I reason.

I first try to identify which method that is used to give the proof. I am however so bad at identifying if there are any "hidden" quantifiers in the text. (if there are could somone point it out) Maybe  $\forall$ series ?

"Pick a number r" is also giving me the impression that "for all" is the quantifier and that we are trying to construct a series that is larger than the series given and at the same time converges.

I therefore start asking this question, how can I show that a series converge. I know that if the tail of the series converge then the entire series converge.

Now since I am not able to figure out if the tail of the series converge. maybe I am able to figure out if there is a series larger then original that converges and evolves in same rate?

I use the choose method to construct this series that is converges. Now I have marked out with blue where I do get stuck, cause I am not able to derive this series as pointed out with the blue arrow.

If someone could point out where my reasoning is faulty, and if the "choose method and for all" is correctly assumed as well as show how this final series is constructed I would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_{N+2}\le ra_{N+1}$ and since $a_{N+1}\le ra_N$, $ra_{N+1}\le r(ra_N)$.  In other words,
$a_{N+2}\le r^2a_N$.

Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: Are there any hidden quantifiers?

Comment: $\forall\,\rho<1,\forall \,\rho<r<1,\,\exists \,N\in\Bbb N^+ ,\,\forall \,n>N \,a_{n+1}/a_n\le r$.